# Does/did Russia or the Soviet Union ever fly rocket planes?

Tags: military, experimental-aircraft, rocket, soviet-union

Did Russia or the Soviet Union ever have their own experimental or military rocket planes (other than the Buran), or did their military merely use jets and other non-rocket aircraft? America flew those many experimental X-planes, did the Soviet Union have any similar planes? Afaik all MiGs are jets.

Comment: Related: [Why Didn't the USSR Build An X-15?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/74071/14897)

Comment: Are you asking if the Soviets ever built any rocket airplane? If so it's a yes/no answer, it would make a better question if you were more specific about the uses of the rocket airplane.

Comment: @GdD I clearly wrote "experimental or military rocket planes". This may include suborbital spaceplanes similar to the X-2 and the X-15. But Mike Sowsun actually answered my question, and the question and answers in ymb1's link are interesting too.

Comment: 5 minutes or less of searching would have supplied you with an answer, why didn't you bother to do that?

Comment: @jwenting You're one of the "friendlier" persons around here, right?

Comment: @Giovanni I try to be, but I like most people here, have not much time for people who don't show any attempts to solve their own problems before asking for help.

Comment: @jwenting Why did you take your time then? I didn't know what exactly to google, and I didn't know of any Russian rocket planes so far. I thought it's best to ask here to get a definite answer. It doesn't hurt you if I ask this. If you don't wanna answer, don't do it (the question had been answered anyway, your comment was entirely superfluous, only good for showing detest).

Comment: Also I'm asking specifically about experimental planes like the X-planes, not just _any_ rocket plane.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes

First, we should clarify the fact that a "rocket engine" *is* a variant of a jet engine. A rocket engine is usually understood as a jet engine that requires external supply of all components of combustion, including the oxidizer.

In a way, that makes things easier, and this is why rocket engines were commonly used at the early stages of jet propulsion development.

Early examples include rocket boosters for traditional piston-driven airplanes. This method is still in use to shorten the take-off distance (down to [zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-length_launch) in some cases), but early on it was tried for "regular" emergency power and, of course, research. (Ram jets also had some limited use then).

The first Soviet 100% jet was [BI-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bereznyak-Isayev_BI-1) (БИ-1) in early 1942.

[image: BI-1]
[wiki Commons](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%98-1#/media/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:%D0%91%D0%98-1_%D0%B2_%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%B8_%D0%92%D0%92%D0%A1_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE.jpg)

BI-1 had a rocket engine burning kerosene and nitric acid. Even though the airplane was designated as "fighter" and had a space provision for guns, it was really a research ariplane, with the maximum time under power of only a few minutes (it never reached even two minutes in real tests).

The first one was corroded away by the acid. The third one (BI-3) was lost, and the test pilot Bakhchivandzhi died, presumably due to [Mach tuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_tuck), which was not understood then.

In the later times, during the "true" jet era, there was [much less cooperation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/74071/why-didnt-the-ussr-build-an-x-15#74099) between the aviation and space industries than in the West. This is one of the reasons why "rocket planes" were a rarity in the USSR, even for research.